How can I get total assets with yfinance?
I tried with the code below:
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        info = stock.info
        totalShares = info.get('sharesOutstanding')
        totalAssets=info.get('totalAssets')

I can not get total assets.

what do you get? is there an error?

I solve it with the code below:
  bs = stock.balance_sheet
  totalAssets = bs.loc['Total Assets'].iloc[1] if 'Total Assets' in bs.index and not bs.empty else None

